# For which real $x$ is this (monster) series convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm practicing for an exam, and got to this example:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left (\frac{x^2n^2-2|x|^3n}{1+2xn^2} \right)^{7n}$$

I rearranged the expression to try to check for which $x$ the expression

$$\frac{1}{ \Big(\frac{1+2xn^2}{x^2n^2-2|x|^3n} \Big) ^{7n}}$$

is smaller than $1/n$ (since it is convergent then), yet to no avail—the exponents are killing me, and comparing it to $1/n^{7n}$ loses some of the solutions if I'm not mistaken.

Ratio test got similarly messy. How to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you apply the root test, that will give you a good idea of the region of convergence.

Recall that a series $\sum a_n$ converges if $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} < 1$ and diverges when it is greater than 1.

The nice thing here is that the $\sqrt[n]{\cdot}$ will get rid of the $n$ in your exponent.

So we see that $$\sqrt[n]{ \left| \left(\frac{x^2n^2 - 2|x|^3n}{1+2xn^2} \right)^{7n}\right| } = \left(\left|\frac{x^2n^2 - 2|x|^3n}{1+2xn^2}\right| \right)^{7}$$

In any case the limiting value of the sequence is $$\left(\frac{x^2}{2|x|}\right)^7 = \left(\frac{|x|}{2}\right)^7$$
This is found by comparing leading coefficients inside the parenthesis. Finally $$(|x|/2)^7 < 1 \implies |x|/2 < 1 \implies |x| < 2.$$

The only thing left is to cover the case when the limit is actually equal to 1. That involves manually inputting $x=2$ and $x=-2$ (your edge cases) and looking for another test that might show they converge or diverge.

Comment: I don't know why but I completely forgot about the root test. Thanks.

Comment: No sweat :) It's a pretty handy tool in calculus. It saves the day more often than not.